# Print stdout in Python without shell escape sequences

Tags: python, shell, escaping, sh

I'm using `sh` to run git commands inside a Python script.

```
In [1]: from sh import git

In [2]: s = git("log", "-1", pretty="format:%h %s")

In [3]: print s
4f14a66 basic debug page
```

This seems to work as expected. However, using this in a Django template gives `[?1h= 4f14a66 basic debug page[m [K[?1l>`. I tried to see what characters were in this string using `repr()`, to no avail:

```
In [4]: print repr(s)
4f14a66 basic debug page
```

It turns out commands in `sh` return a `RunningCommand` that has a `.stdout` attribute:

```
In [5]: type(s)
Out[5]: sh.RunningCommand

In [7]: s.stdout
Out[7]: '\x1b[?1h\x1b=\r4f14a66 basic debug page\x1b[m\r\n\r\x1b[K\x1b[?1l\x1b>'
```

How do I get `"4f14a66 basic debug page"` i.e. the string without the escapes? Running the command from Bash is fine:

```
$ git log -1 --pretty="format:%h %s"
4f14a66 basic debug page
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s.stdout` in the REPL will not print it but display its `repr()`. Use `print s.stdout` to get what you are looking for.

If you do not want any escape codes consider executing it using `subprocess.call()` - with stdout not being a tty most programs do not output any escape sequences.

Comment: Ultimately, I want to use the output in a Django template. `print` understands the escape sequences, but how do I strip them to get a plain string?

Comment: Ah.. did you try `--no-color` when calling git-log?

Comment: No change with `--no-color` sadly.

Comment: `subprocess.check_output(["git", "log", "-1", "--pretty=format:%h %s"])` worked perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/amoffat/sh/issues/132#issuecomment-15312361), correct solution to the problem is to use `_tty_out=False`:

```
>>> str(git('show', format='%cN', s=True))
'\x1b[?1h\x1b=\rHonza Javorek\x1b[m\r\n\r\x1b[K\x1b[?1l\x1b>'

>>> str(git('show', format='%cN', s=True, _tty_out=False))
'Honza Javorek\n'
```

This is also solution for my duplicate question: [Using sh, git show returns special characters - how to get plain output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247009/using-sh-git-show-returns-special-characters-how-to-get-plain-output)