# git show/log without shell escape sequences, for use with python sh

Tags: python, git, shell

I'm using python's sh to script git commands. For example, I do things like

```
import sh
git = sh.git.bake(_cwd='/some/dir/')

project_hash = git('rev-parse', 'HEAD').stdout.strip()
project_branch = git('rev-parse', '--abbrev-ref', 'HEAD').stdout.strip()
project_date = git('log', '-1', '--pretty=format:%ci').stdout.strip()
```

and then I write the project_hash, project_branch and project_date into a database, etc.

The trouble is git sometimes adds shell escape sequences to its output. For example,

```
print(repr(project_hash))
print(repr(project_branch))
print(repr(project_date))
```

leads to

```
'e55595222076bd90b29e184b6ff6ad66ec8c3a03'
'master'
'\x1b[?1h\x1b=\r2012-03-26 01:07:40 -0500\x1b[m\r\n\r\x1b[K\x1b[?1l\x1b>'
```

The first two strings are not a problem, but the last one, the date, has escape sequences.

Is there any way I can get rid of these, e.g. asking git not to output any escape sequences?

I have tried the "--no-color" option with the git log command. That did not help.

I would also be happy to strip them out in python itself, but I don't know how. I tried s.encode('ascii') where s is the date string. That did not make a difference.

[Print stdout in Python without shell escape sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611061/print-stdout-in-python-without-shell-escape-sequences) addresses the same issue. The recommendation there is to use python's subprocess rather than sh. E.g., I could do

```
project_date = subprocess.check_output(["git", "log", "-1", "--pretty=format:%ci"], cwd='/some/dir/')
```

and

```
print(repr(project_date))
```

gives

```
'2012-03-26 01:07:40 -0500'
```

That is what I want, of course. However, if it is possible I would prefer to stick with sh, and so would like to know if I can avoid the escape sequences using sh.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are not color sequences, those look like terminal initialization sequences.  Specifically:

```
ESC [ ? 1 h ESC =
```

is the sequence to turn on function-key-mode and

```
ESC [ ? 1 l ESC >
```

is the sequence to turn it off again.  This suggests that `git log` is running things through your pager.  I'm not quite sure why; normally git suppresses use of the pager when the output is a pipe (as it is with `subprocess.Popen()` at least, and I would think with `sh`, although I have not used the `sh` module).

(Pause to consult documentation...)

Aha!  Per [sh module docs](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/#ttys), by default, the output of an `sh`-module-run command goes through a pseudo-tty.  This is fooling git into running your pager.

As a slightly dirty work-around, you can run `git --no-pager log ...` to suppress the use of the pager, even when running with `sh`.  Or, you can try the `_tty_out=False` argument (again, I have not used the `sh` module, you will have to experiment a bit).  Amusingly, one of the examples at the bottom of the sh module documentation is git!

Comment: The `--no-pager` worked! I did `git = sh.git.bake('--no-pager', _cwd='/some/dir/')` at the start of the original code and all the escape sequences are removed.

Comment: Fixed an anoying bug I ran into

Comment: The `--no-pager` option doesn't work for `git show ...` with git version 1.7, I ended up running `PAGER=cat git show ...` instead.

Comment: The `sh.contrib.git` was specifically build to address it https://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/contrib.html#git

Answer (score 0):

It seems like sh does the right thing. In python 2.7, this:

```
import sh
git = sh.git.bake(_cwd='/tmp/gittest/')

project_hash = git('rev-parse', 'HEAD')
project_branch = git('rev-parse', '--abbrev-ref', 'HEAD')
project_date = git('log', '-1', '--pretty=format:%ci')

print(repr(project_hash).strip())
print(repr(project_branch).strip())
print(repr(project_date).strip())
```

gives me:

```
500ddad67203badced9a67170b42228ffa269f53
master
2013-11-22 00:05:59 +1100
```

If you really want to strip out escapes, use the decoder tools provided by python ([Process escape sequences in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python))

Comment: Strangely, my problems persist. I am using python 2.7.5. And when I use the s.decode('string_escape') method suggested by [the post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python) you mentioned, the escape sequences did not get removed. I'm baffled.

Comment: Try this: `project_date = str(git('log', '-1', '--pretty=format:%ci')).strip()`, then `print(project_date)`