# git diff --color=never escape sequences in output

Tags: python, git

I am trying to use `git diff --color=never` in  a python script, but i realized that there are escape sequences in the output of `git diff`, despite the usage of the `--color=never` option.

This is an example of the output:

```
[u'\x1b[?1h\x1b=\r\x1b[1mdiff --git a/file1 b/file1\x1b[m\x1b[m\r', u'\x1b[1mnew file mode 100644\x1b[m\x1b[m\r', u'\x1b[1mindex 0000000..e69de29\x1b[m\x1b[m\r', u'\x1b[1mdiff --git a/file2 b/file2\x1b[m\x1b[m\r', u'\x1b[1mdeleted file mode 100644\x1b[m\x1b[m\r', u'\x1b[1mindex e69de29..0000000\x1b[m\x1b[m\r', u'\r\x1b[K\x1b[?1l\x1b>']
```

To reproduce you can use this snippet (or something similar):

```
from sh import git


def main():
    changes = git.diff('--color=never', 'master', 'origin/master')
    changes = changes.split('\n')
    print(changes)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have two questions:

Is there a way to avoid that these sequences are printed (e.g. a git option)?

Why are these sequences there and what do they do, because i do not see any colors when i invoke it from the command line.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121664/git-show-log-without-shell-escape-sequences-for-use-with-python-sh

Comment: thanks! gits `--no-pager` option worked for me, too!