# Using sh, git show returns special characters - how to get plain output?

Tags: python, git, sh

I'm using the `sh` Python library: https://amoffat.github.io/sh/ I'm trying to get name and e-mail address of the last commiter. I tried it like this:

```
from sh import git
name = str(git('show', format='%cN', s=True))
```

While on some machines this is perfectly safe, on some other ones the `name` variable will contain also some strange characters:

```
'\x1b[?1h\x1b=\rHonza Javorek\x1b[m\r\n\r\x1b[K\x1b[?1l\x1b>'
```

I believe they're some coloring escape characters, but the output actually isn't colored at all and even if I add `--no-color` to the command, the output stays the same.

How can I get rid of these characters? I tried to turn off colors in various ways and also some algorithms for removing the characters (e.g. those in [Filtering out ANSI escape sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506033/filtering-out-ansi-escape-sequences) or [How to strip color codes used by mIRC users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970545/how-to-strip-color-codes-used-by-mirc-users) or [How can I remove the ANSI escape sequences from a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693701/how-can-i-remove-the-ansi-escape-sequences-from-a-string-in-python)), but nothing really worked well with my string.

Comment: I found the solution myself and I posted it as an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36252138/325365